# Changing Text Size in Tabs of Tab Layout, when Pressed in android

Tags: android, tabs

I want to know how to change text size larger on selected tab in `TabLayout`. In other android view components, it can be achieve using selector but I've tried selector on `TabLayout` ,it's not working. How can I achieve this? 
Thank u for paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
            ********---BottomNavigation Style---********
<style name="AppTheme.BottomNavigation"parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="labelVisibilityMode">labeled</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">@style/TextAppearanceActive</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">@style/TextAppearanceInactive</item>
</style>



            ********---Font Size Style---********
<style name="TextAppearanceActive" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_sf_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/font_sf_regular</item>
    <item name="fontStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font10</item>
</style>


//InActive Style
 <style name="TextAppearanceInactive" parent="TextAppearanceActive">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font9</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            style="@style/AppTheme.BottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer below-

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
            if (textView != null) {
                textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.c_white));
                textView.setTextSize(24);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
            if (textView != null) {
                textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.c_grey));
                textView.setTextSize(18);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer looks promising, but textView is null. So it got me nowhere

Comment: TextView textView =  (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition())).getChildAt(1));